# Expand RAID array on HP Dynamic Smart Array B320i controller

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, fakeraid

I have a few HP [ProLiant DL360e Gen8](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/proliant-servers/product-detail.html?oid=5249570) servers that are equipped with the [Dynamic Smart Array B320i RAID controller](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetHTML.aspx?docname=c04168333).

One particular system was shipped with a single disk installed instead of a pair of drives needed for a RAID 1 mirror. I asked for another drive, but went ahead with the OS installation as RAID 0, intending to add the second disk later.

When it arrived, I went through the normal HP array expansion (*transformation*) process using the [HP Smart Storage Administrator](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5409020). Oddly, there were no actual options to add the additional drive to the existing array in the GUI.

So I took a look at the CLI options.

Current array config snippet (*[full configuration here](http://pastebin.com/QipUzQHZ)*):

```
=> ctrl all show config

Dynamic Smart Array B320i RAID in Slot 0 (Embedded)

   Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 1, OK

   Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 0, OK
   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 212343  MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (72.0 GB, RAID 0, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 300 GB, OK)

   unassigned

      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
```

---

Using the command line `hpssacli` tool to initiate the transformation yielded an error:

```
# hpssacli controller slot=0 array A add drives=allunassigned

Error: This operation is not supported with the current configuration. Use the 
       "show" command on devices to show additional details about the
       configuration.
Reason: Transformation size zero. This may indicate that 
       there is no battery or a failed battery on the controller.
```

---

A quick check of the B320i controller's [specifications](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetHTML.aspx?docname=c04168333) show:

```
Provides increased server uptime by providing advanced storage functionality:
- Online RAID level migration (between any RAID level/with FBWC ) 
- Online drive firmware upgrade
- Pre-Failure Warranty
```

It would seem that the Smart Array B320i should be capable of a RAID level migration, provided an FBWC unit is present. The controller in question has a healthy 512MB FBWC unit and SAS license key installed.

However, [this brief note](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03696353&lang=en) buried deep within the HP website says:

> The user has a B320i, with the 512MB cache module and SAS license
>   installed. Additional drives have been added to the server and user
>   wishes to expand the array, then extend the logical drive. When
>   looking through the Array Configuration Utility (ACU) there is no
>   option to do this.
>
> B series Smart Array Controllers do not allow for this functionality. This option is available on most P series Smart Array Controllers. If the user wishes to upgrade to the P series Smart Array, instructions for performing this action are included in [the documentation]

So, while I can accept that there may be incorrect (*misleading*) language in the product literature, what can I actually do about this?

I appear to be stuck with a RAID controller that has no ability to modify its physical or logical drive configuration. Is there any other option for this system other than a full reformat, array reconfiguration and rebuild?

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Anyway to dump/restore to a properly initialized physical raid-set and then do an export/import process and move the disks to the target system?

Comment: @mdpc I don't have another or spare set of disks to work with. This is a pretty routine operation that one would expect to function properly.

Comment: Battery uncharged or defect by any chance?

Comment: @Striker_84 It's a Capacitor-backed flash setup. Yes, it's healthy.

Comment: firmware / software version most recent? e.g. controller firmware should be 15.10.07.00 and hp smart storage software 2.0.23.0.

Comment: @Striker_84 Yes, the firmware and software are completely up-to-date. Also see the [full configuration output](http://pastebin.com/QipUzQHZ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This just doesn't work.**

I'll accept that the documentation which influenced the decision to buy this solution was flawed and that the [HP Smart Array B320i RAID controller](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetHTML.aspx?docname=c04168333) is not capable of logical drive expansion, migration or modification.

It's a shame.

In this specific case, I had to rebuild the server in order to add a new disk to the array set.

Comment: That's horrible........